# How to remove warning "Conditional cast from 'Any' to 'AnyObject' always succeeds"

Tags: ios, swift, nsurlsession, nsjsonserialization

I create a class and I'm getting an warning message when I try to cast an object as AnyObject. 
The warning is: " Conditional cast from 'Any' to 'AnyObject' always succeeds "
How can I remove this warning from my file ?

Here is my code:

```
class WebServices
{
    class func getRequest( urlString: String, successBlock :@escaping (_ response :AnyObject)->Void, errorMsg:@escaping (_ errorMessage :String)->Void )
    {
        var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: urlString)!)
        request.httpMethod = "GET"

        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data, urlResponse, error) in

            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                if(error == nil)
                {
                    do {
// Here is the warning 
                        let responseJSON = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .mutableContainers) as? AnyObject 
                        guard let _ = responseJSON else {
                            errorMsg("Some error has been occurred!")
                            return
                        }
                        successBlock(responseJSON!)
                    }
                    catch
                    {
                        errorMsg("Some error has been occurred!")
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    errorMsg(error!.localizedDescription)
                }
            }
        }
        task.resume()
    }
}
```

Thank you guys for your time if you are reading this !

Comment: Why do you do `as? AnyObject`? Why do you use `AnyObject` and not `Any`?

Comment: @Larme will be the same warning if I modify from AnyObject to Any. The idea is to remove the warning.

Comment: Question is: "What's the message then"? Read it. Try to understand it: " Conditional cast from 'Any' to 'Any' always succeeds " Why cast Any to Any? What's a cast? Why cast at all?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This function

```
let responseJSON = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .mutableContainers) as? AnyObject
```

returns `Any` and you cast it to `AnyObject` which nearly the same , it's better to cast to the expected json content whether it's an array or dictionary

```
let responseJSON = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!) as? [String:Any]
```

Or

```
let responseJSON = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!) as? [Any]
```

and change the completion accordingly

Comment: Is working with [String: Any]
If I use [Any] is not getting me any data from the API. Thank you so much Sh_Khan !